# Switching Spark versions and distributing jars to all nodes - Yarn v Standalone

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I have an environment setup with both Spark 2.0.1 and 2.2.0. both run in standalone mode and contain a master and 3 slaves. They each sit on the same servers and are configured in the exact same way. I only ever want to run one at once and to do so I set the SPARK_HOME environment version to the location of the Spark version I wish to start and run start-master.sh and start-slaves.sh in the bin folder of that particular version.

I have a jar file which I wish to use for all Spark programs to be executed with. This is regardlss of version. I'm aware I could just pass it in the `spark-submit` `--jars` parameter but I don't want to have to account for any transfer time in the job execution so am currently placing the the jar file in the jars folder of each of the master and slave nodes prior to startup. This is a regular task as the jar file gets updated quite often.

If I wish to switch Spark versions I must run stop-slaves.sh and stop-master.sh in the bin folder of the version I wish to stop, then go through the above process again.

Key things I wish achieve are that I can differentiate the transfer of jars from execution timings and that I can easily switch versions. I am able to do this with my current setup but its all done manually and I'm looking at automating it. However, I don't want to spend time doing this if theres already a solution that will do what I need.

Is there a better way of doing this? I'm currently looking at Yarn to see if it can offer anything.

Comment: Spark 2.2 should be binary compatible with any code in Spark 2.0.1 (according to the documentation). Not clear why you need both

Comment: Why do you need to run 2 separate versions of Spark ? Maybe you should address that first.

Comment: It's for testing. I need to test on two versions. I don't have them running in parallel though.